Model works in tensorflow 2.15 perfectly but unable to import the model in tensorflow 2.16
I am facing an unusual issue which is not being found on the internet as well. I have trained a Classification model on tensorflow 2.15. This model runs perfectly but when when I try to import that model I get the following error.
ValueError: Invalid value for argument reduction. Expected one of {'sum', 'none', 'sum_over_batch_size', None}. Received: reduction=auto
The expected result is that my model which is trained in tensorflow version 2.15 can be imported and can run in tensorflow 2.16.
Any  help in this issue is appreciated. Thanks.
